# Laravel's app() Container class magic __get with braces

Tags: php, laravel, class

By debugging laravel in `$x = app()->resolved;` i get to this magic method

```
public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this[$key];
    }
```

in `Illuminate\Container\Container`

And I wanna understand that, but I can't figure out what this does.

What is `return $this[$key];` ? `$this[$key]` like this is keyed array

I understand that `$this->xxx` is getting $xxx property of `this` instance.

But  what `$this[$key]` is?

And why next line that is executing in code is

```
public function offsetGet($key)
    {
        return $this->make($key);
    }
```

Can't figure it out and understand even with debbuging now and thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any class which implements the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) can behave like an array when used with `[]`

Assuming:

```
 class MyArrayAccessibleClass implements \ArrayAccess { }
 $class = new MyArrayAccessibleClass();
```

The following pairs are equivalent:

```
$variable =  $class["index"]
$variable = $class->offsetGet("index");

$class["index"] = $value;
$class->offsetSet("index",$value);

isset($class["index"]);
$class->offsetExists("index");

unset($class["index"]);
$class->offsetUnset("index");
```

In particular the laravel `Application` extends `Container` which implements `ArrayAccess`